# Incremental Backup (Patch file generation)using Delta Encoding in C#

Tags: c#, backup, increment

I'm doing a small backup utility.This backup should be incremental. Suppose I have 2 files, then my backup destination must contain differences of those two files only (Patch file generation). I googled it to search the ways to do this! I found "Delta encoding". But I don't have idea about how to implement that.?

Please anyone suggest any ideas to accomplish this.. And suggest any sample C# code also!

Thank you!

Comment: Are the files binary or text?

Comment: Now I'm trying with text files .But my final project requirement want to backup in binary files .!